# Sidebar bootstrap scrolling block responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a sidebar made ​​CSS with Bootstrap.
It's fixed, so when I open it with a small smartphone some content can not be seen, and if I go down the sidebar is block.

**This is a sample photo**

[image]

**And this is the code:**

```css
.sidebar-offcanvas{-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: auto;
  width:70%;
  background-color: #262e56;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 0;margin: 0;
  position:fixed;
  top:165px;
  left: -70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
  <ul data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="120" id="affix" class="nav nav-stacked">
    <li> <a data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav"> <i class="fa fa-th"></i> Menu </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Supporto </a></li>
    <li><a> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> I principi della conbustione </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Agenti estinguenti - 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Agenti estinguenti - 2 </a></li>   
    <li><a href="#"> Gli estintori - 1 </a></li>   
    <li><a href="#"> Gli estintori - 2 </a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>

this is the tutorial to do this slidbar: http://www.marchettidesign.net/2014/04/creare-un-sidebar-menu-responsive-stile-app-con-bootstrap/
help me to add scrolling to the slidebar
```

Comment: Well, it is positioned fixed so it works like it should, right? It stays where you have set it to be. What you're trying to do here, what should happen to the sidebar? What is the question?

Comment: It would be helpful to debug, if you can provide a Jsfiddle.

Comment: I wish that when I flow down even the slidebar flows
now get stuck

Comment: This id the tutorial to create this sidebar http://www.marchettidesign.net/2014/04/creare-un-sidebar-menu-responsive-stile-app-con-bootstrap/ help me to add scrolling to the slidebar

Comment: position fix will always set the div at same fix position, Instead try the combination of Position `Absolute` and `relative`. Also create `jsfiddle` so that we can help you.

Comment: thank you Rajiv Pingale, i resolve my problem with absolute and relative.